# Multiple handlers conflicting

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have nested cursor loops, and I wanted to catch error 1329, no data fetch, on the outer loop. How can I do this?

I tried to add a second CONTINUE HANDLER for this outer loop cursor but it catches nested loop errors (not wanted), and it ends up not triggering the nested handler.

I have this:

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR select data, valor_split, valor_div from tbl1 where data >= primeira_mov and id_papel = idpapel order by data DESC;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1329 BEGIN
        SET nodata_issue = 1;
        SET dateof_issue = datasplit;
    END;
```

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a flag to 1 when you enter the inner loop, set it to 0 when you leave it.

Then:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1329 BEGIN
    IF flag_innerloop = 0 THEN do_something;
    ELSE do_something_else;

END;
```

Comment: That's clever, thanks. I still have the issue of the second handler conflicting with nested handler (second is triggered, nested is not), I guess I'll just change my logic and remove it